# Check if CellPainting row index is above 0

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a dataGridView table for my project. I wanted to test out my skill of putting a red triangle in the corner of a cell for future reference and it works. However, the triangle only shows up on the header cells. I've put an if statement to move the triangles from the headers to the bottom cells but it just isn't working no matter what. They always stick to the top like in this photo:

[image: Photo]

Here's my code, any ideas what to change?

```
private void registerView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        Point[] points = { new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, 0), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right - 10, 0), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, 10) };
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), points);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your points are all located at y=0.

Comment: Also note that when you code CellPaintnig you need to do a little more than just add graphics! Example: `e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);` before and `e.Handled = true;` after